# How does the air traffic system on Coruscant work?

Tags: star-wars, vehicles

I'm currently watching Episode III, and when looking at the air traffic on Coruscant, it appears that traffic moves on level planes that differ by elevation, and so, I wondered: how are these elevations established? For example, is it based on the distance being traveled by the vehicle, or, is it by velocity? And then, are vehicles able to transition from one elevation to another while in-flight? Or, is it the fact that, once they've established an elevation, they must maintain it until they've reached [near] their destination?

So, ultimately: How does the air traffic system on Coruscant work? Does there exist any evidence [either in the movies or in books] that outlines how this finely-tuned transportation system works?

[image]

Comment: I was slightly hesitant in posting this question because I feel it may be too broad. If you also think this, please try to recommend a way for me to make it more specific, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: [Legends article on the matter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant_Air_Traffic_Control)

Comment: Ahem; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Coruscant_traffic_control_organizations

Comment: @Valorum Those are just organizations. I am asking about the regulations themselves, or, at least, some hint as to why certain vehicles are higher up, why some are lower, etc. This may then lead to answers that mention how some routes may only exist on one plane, and that higher speeds take place at lower altitudes for *xyz* reasons.

Comment: @Charles - Meh. The books are listed. Someone else can get themselves some easy rep by copying and pasting the relevant pages

Comment: Only Jedi could change lanes in-flight.

Answer (score 9):

## Non-canon answer

Traffic is organised in 3D traffic lanes, governed by a complex set of rules, and policed by [Coruscant Air Traffic Control](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant_Air_Traffic_Control) (name varies according to the Era).

A quote from *"Legacy Of The Force Book 2 - Bloodline"* (Legends continuity)

> It was hard to seal off a neighborhood in a place like Coruscant. The intersections were three-dimensional and required six CSF traffic division repulsorlift ships for each skylane junction that Jacen needed to have blocked off. He stood on the platform of a military assault vessel, a matte-gray gunship not unlike its CSF counterpart, watching two of the CSF ships hover into position. It was still dark; the CSF vessels had no navigation lights showing. Jacen could only see them because the light pollution on Coruscant meant that Galactic City was never truly pitch black, and he could pick out the shape of the hull when it moved.

I found no canon texts explaining the matter.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like they’d have to have specific clearance or permission to travel on a certain level. Also while there are some spots you can see the levels all at once, some of them may lead them different places.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could [edit] in some evidence to back it up.